# facing issue in installing new package

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I am using `react-native-base` for using react-native components.
I have already installed previously

`react-native-document-picker
react-native-fcm
react-native-image-crop-picker
react-native-vector-icons
react-navigation`

But now Whatever new Package/Library I am Installing in my existing app, some of my existing packages/files are getting removed, and because of it So many errors are coming. why is this happening while installing any of the new package.
Here is screenshot I am attaching when installing new library

[image]

**package.json**

```
{
"name": "myApp",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
},
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.3",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.0.9"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.4.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.4.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
},
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `package.json`?, also try if it still occurs after upgrading `npm`

Comment: Ahh, I checked by creating new project 'react-native init myApp' and trying to install 'react-native-star-rating' Still I am facing the same.

Comment: It's creating package-lock.json file automatically in fresh project.

Comment: {
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.3",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.0.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.4.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.4.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}

Comment: Try upgrading your `npm` to latest using this `npm install npm@latest -g` and see it the problem still occurs

Comment: It Works :) Thanks :)